# why is there a delay between (DR register written) and (data really showed) in UART on STM32F103CB?

Tags: timer, uart, stm32f1

I'm curious about the delay time between the title mentioned, I toggled an IO when I wrote data into UART->DR, the delay time varies from 3 micro seconds to 10x micro seconds
[image]

[image]

```
int main(void)
{
  /* initial code generated by STMCubeMX */
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_Delay(50);

    if (USART_GetFlagStatus(&huart1, USART_SR_TXE) == SET)
    {
      USART_SendData(&huart1, 'F');
    }
  }
}


void USART_SendData(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Data)
{
  assert_param(IS_USART_ALL_PERIPH(USARTx));

  assert_param(IS_USART_DATA(Data));

  GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_1;                   // Tick an IO pin for debugging
  GPIOB->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_1 << 16u;  // reset bit

  huart->Instance->DR = (uint8_t)(Data & (uint8_t)0x00FF);      // send data (write DR)
}
```

I'm not sure whether the time jitters is related with BAUD rate 9600(104 micro seconds/bit),

Isn't the data should be showed immediately when DR register written????

And why isn't the delay time all the same(or close)?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the data should be showed immediately when DR register written????

Not necessarily.
You are only showing us high-level language source code.
Have you looked at the actual instruction trace to determine the instruction time between these operations?
How do you ensure that no interrupt is serviced between these operations?

> And why isn't the delay time all the same(or close)?

Apparently that depends on the design of the UART.
You report that the baudrate is 9600, and (as expected) the intervals for each bit appear to be slightly longer than 100microsec.

The fact that the observed latency is less than one bit interval is significant.
The typical UART uses a clock (aka the baudrate generator) that is 16 times faster than the configured baudrate.
This faster-than-necessary clock is needed to [oversample](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207870/uart-receiver-sampling-rate) the receiving signal, which can arrive at anytime, i.e. it's *asynchronous* communication after all.

[image]

For the transmit clock, the baudrate generator is divided down to the nominal baudrate.
So for transmission, that clock quantizes in time when each bit (of the frame) will start (and end) its transmission.
Since the write to the UART TxD data register is performed by the CPU, and that operation is *not synchronized* with the transmit clock, you should therefore expect a random delay of up to one bit interval before the start bit of the frame appears on the wire.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Sorry for one more question, is there any way to re-initialize the transmitter CLK? Does recalling MX_USART2_UART_Init(); work? Or if I set a super high baud rate and set back to 9600, will this reset the Cnt in the Baud Rate Generator?

Comment: You could experiment, but any synchronization between CPU and the UART's  transmit clock would be coincidental and temporary.  I suppose that the phase of the transmit clock could be shifted so that transmission could be started ASAP when the Tx shift register is loaded, but that is probably an added feature that has a low cost vs benefit ratio.  Maybe there is a UART out there that has such a feature.